# Assign a higher priority to a specific process by default

Tags: fedora, process, nice, priority

I would like to configure my desktop Linux system so that whenever I start running a specific program (run that processes of this program) the respective process gets assigned a high priority. How to do this?

I am aware I can do so individually for each instance of running the program, i.e. for specific processes. But how to configure a default for the program (i.e. for all future processes)?

Kernel version: 4.10.11-200.fc25.x86_64

Comment: Wrap the specific application with a shell script that executes the original using `nice`?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/895583/how-to-set-default-nice-value-for-a-particular-program

Answer (score 2):

There is a program called "[auto nice daemon](http://and.sourceforge.net/)" which does this. It runs in the background, and when a process matching a particular pattern appears in the process table, it sets its niceness automatically.

You can use this — but, you might be a bit disappointed, because the Linux scheduler has a lot to balance and increasing priority won't necessarily give a magic speed boost. You can even run into situations where it makes things *worse*, because your high-priority process might "starve" lower-priority processes that your application might actually depend on to move forward.

So, instead, you could look at something like [tuned](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/20/html/Power_Management_Guide/tuned.html), which has performance profiles for a variety of different workloads. *Or*, if you are adventurous, you could look at [Con Kolivas desktop scheduler patches](http://www.users.on.net/~ckolivas/kernel/), which aim to optimize desktop experience. This is really hard to measure and somewhat controversial — many people swear by it, while others are skeptical. (There's a Linux Weekly News article on the latest iteration at [The MuQSS CPU scheduler](https://lwn.net/Articles/720227/) — currently behind a paywall but will become free on May 4th.)

Answer (score 1):

you'll want to look into the [nice](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nice.1.html) and [renice](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/renice.1.html) utilities. To give your process a higher CPU priority you have to have root/sudo privileges. You can either use `nice` to start the process with a higher priority or `renice` to change it to a higher priority afterward.

```
(terminal1):~# nice -n -10 sleep 100
(terminal2):~# top -b -n1 | grep sleep
23580 root      10 -10    4508   1244   1156 S 0.000 0.008   0:00.00 sleep
(terminal1):~# sleep 100
(terminal2):~# top -b -n1 | grep sleep
23888 root      20   0    4508   1316   1228 S 0.000 0.008   0:00.00 sleep
(terminal2):~# renice -n -10 23888
23888 (process ID) old priority 0, new priority -10
(terminal2):~# top -b -n1 | grep sleep
23888 root      10 -10    4508   1356   1268 S 0.000 0.008   0:00.00 sleep
```

Comment: your answers prompts me to be more specific. The issue is not changing niceness once but by default for all future processes of a specific programme.

Comment: Unfortunately, to my knowledge, I don't think there's any established method of doing that per program. I know there is per user in the limits.conf, but I don't know of a way per program. A work-around might be to move the executable for that program to a slightly different name. Then create a simple bashscript for that program under its name that executes the renamed program with the adjusted nice value? I've never tested something like that though.